# Failed to build gem native extension when installing Calabash Android on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ruby, ubuntu, calabash

I want to install Calabash Android on Ubuntu(13.10). I have gem (1.8.23) and ruby (1.9.3p194) installed and tried to run "sudo gem install calabash-android" but keep getting messages saying "Failed to build gem native extension", below is the full messages:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing calabash-android:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
```

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `'

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/gherkin-2.12.2 for inspection.

I tried "sudo apt-get update" but it didn't fix the issue. And I also checked gcc so it shouldn't be build issue. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This works for me: http://techespanto.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/upgrade-ruby-version-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 5):

While installing ruby, select development version or full version, so on my system with ubuntu 12.04, i would use

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

also please make sure android home path and ant path is proper

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rbenv` that manage perfectly ruby gems versions like `nvm` does for `node.js`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
$ git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash
$ sudo apt-get install rbenv
$ exec $SHELL
$ rbenv install 2.2.2
$ rbenv global 2.2.2
$ ruby -v
$ echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
$ gem install bundler
```